# Append existing PDF file

Tags: java, itext

I have some code that generates a PDF file programmatically and I need to append to it the existing file (to the end of generated one). Can somebody give an example or link?

Thank you

UPD#1: Actually I am looking for some piece of code of merging existing file and byte's array (of programmatically generated file)

Comment: where is ur code?what have u tried?

Comment: I didn't tried beacuse did't find any code snippets for that purpose

Comment: Then you have to use better search terms. The first hit I got on Google provides me with a nice sample program to merge PDFs (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/itext-tutorial-merge-split-pdf-files-using-itext-jar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all repliers, I have found the solution:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
writer.setPageEvent(new FooterGenerator());

document.open();
document.setMargins(MARGIN_LEFT, MARGIN_RIGHT, MARGIN_TOP, MARGIN_BOTTOM);
document.add(generateHeader());
document.add(generateContent());
appendTermsAndConditions(writer, document, context.getRealPath("/files/terms-and-conditions.pdf");
document.close();

protected void appendTermsAndConditions(PdfWriter writer, Document document, String fileName) throws IOException {
   File f = new File(fileName);
   if (f.exists()) {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
    int pagesCount = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfImportedPage page;
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++) {
        document.newPage();
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, document.getPageNumber() + 1);
        cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: It overwrites the file, doesn't append.

Answer (score 0):

Itext is the good solution.
To append , you need to read the already present data and write it to the next file.

```
PdfTextExtractor parser =new PdfTextExtractor(new PdfReader("D:/Text.pdf"));
String text1 = parser.getTextFromPage(3);
```

And before you write your code that generates a PDF file programmatically , you need to add text1.

Comment: And what if that existing PDF file contains images etc.? How can I add all content without loose anything?

Comment: Actually i have not tried to append.Now i am currently trying to do as you want.wait and lets see if it works.you can also try the same thing at your side.

Comment: I am sorry..this method will extracts only the text part and not the images.